# printing a variable in AWK with AWK output for csv file

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a variable that is populated from a log file. it is capturing the host name of a server for use in the awk printout. im making a CSV file that prints the MAC address, port number then the host name.

here is that variable

```
hostVar=$(awk '/#/' macAddress.log)
```

this works fine
what I need is to print the variable in my next awk statement so that it prints the var last. below works fine and prints MAC,HOST

```
grep -Ff masterList macAddress.log | awk '{print $2 "," $4}' >> output.csv
```

I am using a master list to filter out the MAC addresses I need to capture. the end result needs to look like this MAC,PORT,HOST

```
grep -Ff masterList.csv macAddress.log | awk '{print $2 "," $4 "," $hostVar}' >> output.csv
```

obviously that doesnt work but I need the host name in the CSV file next to the port number (MAC then port num then host name)

```
0011.2233.4455,Gi1/0,Switch1
```

(switch1 being what $hostVar is populated with)

Comment: What are you expecting '$test' to equal? Right now, AWK is looking for a awk variable named 'test' and finds none, so it defaults to 0. Then AWK looks at the $ operator and evaluates it to be equal to the entire input because $0 equal the entire input.

Comment: sorry, typo. anything referenced to $test should be $hostVar

Answer (score 0):

Right now $hostvar is trying to be resolved by AWK. Try

```
awk '{print $2 "," $4 "," '$hostVar'}'
```

to use the $hostvar from bash. Single quotes block variable being stuck into strings, in bash.

Comment: that doesnt work. What I need is to print 2 matches then a variable. the var captures the host name and I need it to print 2 other findings.